# Is there a faster way to multiply by 2 on SIMD (without using muliplication)?

Tags: c++, c, performance, optimization, simd

A trick with the old floats used to be to never multiply by 2 but to add an operand with itself, as, 2*a = a + a. Is the old trick still feasible to use with SSE/SSE2/SSSE3/NEON/... instruction sets and the like today? My operand would be a vector (say, 4 floats, that I want to multiply by 2). What about multiplying by 3, 4 ...?

Comment: That really depends on the underlying hardware but I suppose you could do that as well

Comment: It depends on what resource you're bounded by. Most processors have separate SSE FP-Add and FP-Mul. The one that is faster will depend on which (if any) you are limited by and whether you are latency bound.

Comment: Maybe a shift left of 1 would be faster?  Anyway, in this day and age of optimizing compilers, the optimizer would more than likely perform this without you having to explicitly do this.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie You can't shift floats. And compilers currently do not do strength-reduction on SSE intrinsics. Because they assume that if you're using intrinsics, you know what you're doing.

Comment: Wouldn't the answer be visible in the disassembly (i.e., by comparing the disassembly of `2*a` and the disassembly of `a+a`)?

Comment: @barakmanos I think only a profiler could provide an answer.

Comment: You also have to consider that multiply by 2 requires that you actually have the 2 from somewhere. Either it's a register or a memory access.

Comment: @Mysticial My primary motivation for asking this is my old instinct I acquired in school, which is: reduce MULs as much as possible, maybe that's old.

Comment: Boundary cases aside, multiplying a float by 2 is the same as incrementing its exponent field...

Comment: I think the modern advice is to trust your compiler to do the right thing and forget all the old tricks. It's entirely possible that `a+a` and `a*2` will compile to the same code.

Comment: You all seem to be forgetting, that this is not about just one float, but, say, 4 of them. This means incrementing all 4 exponents, or multiplying by 2 all 4 operands.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm still trying to find an example of where this would make a difference. My gut feeling is that if latency is an issue there are cases where `x+x` would be better but if latency is not an issue and only throughput matters then it could be worse. But first let's discuss some hardware.

Let me stick to Intel x86 processors since that's what I know best. Let's consider the following generations of hardware: **Core2/Nehalem, SandyBridge/IvyBridge, and Haswell/Broadwell**.

Latency and throughput for **SIMD** floating pointer arithmetic operations:

- The latency for addition is 3.
- Except for Broadwell the latency for multiplication is 5.
- On Broadwell multiplication has a latency of 3.
- The throughput for addition is 1.
- Except for Haswell and Broadwell the throughput for multiplication is one  1.
- On Haswell and Broadwell the throughput for multiplicatin is 2.
- The throughput for addition and multiplication without FMA is 2.
- The latency for FMA is 5
- The throughput for FMA is 2. This is equivalent to an addition and multiplication throughput of 4.

**Here is a case I'm actually using for generating the Mandelbrot set which has a factor of 2**.  In the main loop two of the most critical lines of code are:

```
x = x*x - y*y + x0;
y = 2*xtemp*y + y0;
```

All of the varible here are SIMD (SSE or AVX) registers so I'm acting on multiple pixels at once (4 with SSE, 8 with AVX for single floating point). I'm using a SIMD class wrapped around the intrinsics for this. For `y` I could do instead

```
y = xtemp*y + xtemp*y + y0
```

What about with FMA?

```
y = fma(2*xtemp, y, y0)
```

or

```
y = xtemp*y + fma(xtemp, y, y0);
```

There are many variations that could be tried. I have not tried `y=xtemp*y + xtemp*y + y0` but I think it would be worse.  Incidentally FMA turns out, so far the way I have implemented it on my Haswell system, not to help much.  My frame rate only increases 15% or so using FMA whereas when I go from using 4 pixels with SSE to 8 pixels with AVX it nearly doubles.

Edit: here are some cases which I though would make a difference but either they don't in practice or they would not make sense to do.

Consider this case

```
for(int i=0; i<n; i++) y[i] = 2*x[i];
```

In this case latency does not matter, throughput matters. On Haswell and Broadwell the throughput for multiplication is twice addition so in this case so it might seem that it would be worse to do `x+x` but since Haswell/Broadwell can only write 32-bytes per clock cycle it does not make a difference.

Here is a case where using `x+x` would seem to be better.

```
for(int i=0; i<n; i++) prod = prod * (2*x[i]);
```

Instead you could do this:

```
for(int i=0; i<n; i++) prod = prod * (x[i]+x[i]);
```

In both these cases it would make no difference since they are dominated by the latency of the multiplication of `prod`.  However, if you unrolled the loops enough times so that latency did not matter then **the second case would be better in general since all the processors can do addition and multiplication at least every clock cycle.** Although Haswell and Broadwell can do two multiplications per clock cycle they can also do two multiplications and additions per clock cycle using FMA so even on them this would be better.

However, in this case the smart thing to do is

```
for(int i=0; i<n; i++) prod *= x[i];
prod *= pow(2,n);
```

So it would not be necessary to do `x+x` instead of `2*x`.

Comment: If you have an example where you can measure (not just theoretical analysis) that gcc replacing 2*x with x+x significantly pessimizes the code, compiler writers might be interested in seeing a PR (though I don't think it would be easy to do much about it).

Comment: @MarcGlisse, sure, if I have time I'll write it up tonight on my Haswell system and show the results here.  I already have a scale write bandwidth test (`y[i] =k*x[i]`). I expect it to be half as fast on Haswell doing `y[i] = x[i]+x[i]` instead of `y[i] = 2*x[i]`.

Comment: @MarcGlisse, you're correct, actually my example won't make a difference because Haswell/Broadwell can only write 64 bytes per clock cycle. I have to fix my answer.

Comment: Sounds like you just need more additions, say 2*x-x-x-x (compiled without -ffast-math) until memory bandwidth becomes irrelevant and the adder is saturated but not the multiplier.

Comment: @MarcGlisse, sorry, what example are you referring to? What do you mean by "2*x-x-x-x"?

Comment: Instead of `y[i]=2*x[i]` you could have a bigger computation, like `y[i]=2*x[i]-(x[i]+1)-x[i]`, using only additions. At least from your explanation it seems to be the kind of example where you would expect mul to be faster than add.

Comment: @MarcGlisse, oh I see your point. I could test that. I was trying to find examples that could be useful in practice and not just show something that could be done but would not make sense to do.

Comment: @MarcGlisse, what about `sum = sum + 2*x`? That could be done `sum = sum + x + x` which I think would be worse in general. But that's `silly` as well because in practice you would do `for(int i=0; i<n; i++) sum +=x; sum*=2;` It's difficult to find an example where in practice it would matter.

Comment: Just to be clear I'm trying to find performance so I'm assuming that floating point math is associative (i.e. with -ffast-math).

Comment: In my job, we absolutely need the precision (the algorithms crash otherwise) so we can't assume associativity. But we still try to get the best performance we can within these constraints, it isn't a contradiction.

Comment: @MarcGlisse, allowing associative floating point arithmetic does not cause a loss in precision. It causes a loss in reliability. There is no guarantee that when you run on another system you will get the same result. But that's not due to a loss in precision. It's like having an unknown seed each time you use a PRNG. It does not mean your PRNG are less useful it just means you can't promise the same list of random numbers every time you run.

Comment: @MarcGlisse, of course there are cases where forcing the associative can avoid catastrophic cancellation but what I means is there is no reason a priori that `sum = (sum + x) + x` would be better than `sum = sum + (x+x)`.

Comment: @MarcGlisse, small correction, Haswell/Broadwell can only write 32 bytes per clock cycle (one AVX register).

Answer (score 5):

Compiler writers are clever. For floating point numbers x, 2.0 * x and x + x are absolutely identical. Therefore, a compiler is quite capable to replace 2.0*x with x + x and vice versa, depending what is faster.

And that can be complicated. Addition is usually faster. But consider a processor which can do say one multiplication and an addition per cycle. Then you would want to replace 2*x and 2*y with 2*x and y+y. If you have an operation 2*x and y+z then you don't want to replace 2*x with x+x because then you have two additions which you can only do in two cycles. Then there are processors with fused-multiply add which can calculate a*b + c in one operation. So you wouldn't want to change 2*x + y to (x + x) + y.

Best to leave it to the compiler.

Comment: They are not as clever, as you think. For example, with clang, you can't write 2 * a, if a is a vector, you need to create a vector of all 2s and then multiply this vector by another vector and clang afaik does not look inside the vector you multiply with, if there are just 2s in it.

Comment: @user1095108 Please complain to your favorite clang vendor, gcc is accepting 2*a and turning it to a+a just fine ;-) Though you are right that compilers are not that clever, afaik gcc never replaces a+a with a*2, whatever the number of other additions nearby and the relative costs.

Comment: @MarcGlisse GCC does not optimize `b = _mm_mul_pd(b,_mm_set1_pd(2));` into `b = _mm_add_pd(b,b)`. IOW, like I said in a comment on the main question, compilers (currently) do not do strength reduction SIMD types.

Comment: @Mysticial I know the intrinsics are not optimized (your first comment was talking about SSE intrinsics instead of SIMD in general, so it was correct), that's why I wrote `2*b` using gcc's vector extension (which does benefit from some optimizations), and why I keep pinging this patch: https://gcc.gnu.org/ml/gcc-patches/2014-07/msg01812.html ;-)

Comment: It's also worth pointing out that Haswell only has one AVX addition port but two AVX multiplication ports so it might not be beneficial to switch to addition.

Comment: @user1095108 It's almost certainly not a question of how clever they may be, but a question of what is a permissible optimization give the language semantics and the hardware.